# Using querySelector to select Div with a specific value

Tags: javascript, html, selector

My current HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="response-view">
  <div class="answer" correct="false">
    <h4>apple</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="answer" correct="false">
    <h4>banana</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="answer" correct="true">
    <h4>pear</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using JavaScript querySelector, how would I go about selecting the specific 'answer' Div with the 'correct' value of 'true'?

Comment: You should use the syntactically proper `data-*` attributes. E.g. `data-correct="true"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select nodes by their attributes and attribute values by using square brackets, e.g. `tag.class[attribute="value"]`.

Working example using your code above, should log "Pear" to the console:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.answer[correct="true"]').textContent);
```

```html
<div id="response-view">
  <div class="answer" correct="false">
    <h4>apple</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="answer" correct="false">
    <h4>banana</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="answer" correct="true">
    <h4>pear</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```